# The project needs to be deployed before it can be started

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Whenever I am starting to test an Windows Phone app (even a blank app) on emulator, I am getting error "**The project needs to be deployed before it can be started**". The emulator will be started & run successfully, still no luck in deploying app on emulator. **Getting error DEP6100 & DEP6200.**

[image: ERROR on WP8.1 Emulator]

[image: ERROR on W10M Emulator]

These are the stuffs I tried till now:

1. Checked "deploy" option in 'Configuration Manager'.
2. Tried deploying Windows 10 Mobile, Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows Phone 8 blank apps on different types of emulators.

Although I am able to run apps on my device.

*I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on Windows 10 Enterprise.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced problem like that and I fixed it by right click on project > properties > change platform target to X86.
[image: Image below describe that]

Answer (score 4):

The Emulator is x86 based and Phone is ARM architecture. To run the app in the emulator, change the CPU to x86 in the toolbar and compile it. Now you can deploy te App to the Emulator and test it.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. Although the solution didn't work.

Comment: @Ashish Sharma, This answer should solve the problem, but I tested to debug on ARM emulator as it in your picture, it gets the error: Unable to deploy an ARM package to an x86 emulator. Change the build configuration to x86 or Neutral, or attach an ARM device.

Comment: @Grace-Feng-MSFT I have updated the screenshot as that was confusing the matter. Please tell me what to be done now.

Answer (score 0):

I just started playing with Xamarin Forms, and ran into this error after following the [Xamarin Forms Quickstart Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/). The error message actually said to Run the Deploy... for the project that you are trying to run. Deploying the project seems to install some Windows dependencies that might be required to run the UMP. After deploying the project, it ran without issue as a Windows Desktop app, or if you change to Device, then install emulator, as Windows Phone app.

Answer (score -1):

This error was relentlessly happening to me as well, and I found out that it was because my project was saved on a SanDisk SD card. If I simply moved the entire solution to my C drive, it built without issue, but on the D drive, it would give this error.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was for, but this was a legit fact. Something about having a Solution on the mounted drive was causing this error.

Comment: Had the same issue with Google Drive. Error persisted as long as the project folder was located on the drive. Moved to a local machine disk and all was well.